# List of jar's names on tomcat WEB-INF

Tags: java, tomcat, reflection

i would like to get a help on this subject.
i'm new on this subject so if i not explain correctly, i apologize.
i run webapps project so its mean when i run the project, tomcat start to create a webapp file (war file) on the commant, first 'clean install' and then 'tomcat7:run-war'
i run the project on eclipse.
my question is how i can get the name of the jar/s that created on war file while runing ?
i saw when i do 'clean install', under the root folder there is target folder which there created the jar who i looking to read his name.
i thougut about reflection but i dont know how exactly i need to do it.
thanks for everone for his help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you execute this code in the jar file you should be able to get its name:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/320595/7746397